# wpf ribboncontrol QAT

Tags: wpf, ribbon, ribboncontrolslibrary

When using Ribboncontrol october 2010 release from Microsoft, even if I don't use QAT I get a right click event "show quick access toolbar" (which doesn't do anything). How can this be disabled ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the following does not do the task:

```
<r:Ribbon x:Name="Ribbon"  
            Title="title" IsMinimized="False">
            <r:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
                <r:RibbonApplicationMenu Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            </r:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            <r:Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
                <r:RibbonQuickAccessToolBar Visibility="Collapsed" />
            </r:Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
...
```

Take care that the context-menu also does not disapear, when you have disabled all other features of the ribbon.

Sorry, I thought I solved the problem some time ago, but actually I didn't.

Comment: thanks SwissCoder. Indeed I tried that also and it doesn't do the trick ;-(